# Run a command while CPU is under 80%

Tags: bash, cpu-usage

I'm trying to run a command every 10 minutes while usage of CPU is under 80%. I'm not used to bash scripting. I've found a way to get the total use of CPU ``top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}'` and then I want to compare with a maximum of 80%. But I'm not sure why I cannot compare both. Here the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAX=80
CPU=`top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}'`

while true
  do
    if $CPU < $MAX
      then
        echo $CPU  # This is an example
        CPU=`top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}'`
        sleep 10m
      fi
    done
```

The script fails because interpret the numbers as a command...  (`cannot open 80: No such file`)
Why I cannot compre `$MAX` and `$CPU`? and how would you tackle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why you would want that. Not disturbing the system when it is under heavy load ? Your "top" will anyway. Not to say that, depending on the real time needed by your command, the cpu load could rise above 80%. What about taking care of scheduling policies instead? (  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html )

Comment: @MC68020 Thanks, I'll take a look on that option. I quite new to this, and sometimes is not clear which would be the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<` is used for
[redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html). If
you need to compare integers:

```
if [ "$MAX" -gt "$CPU" ]
```

But `$CPU` can also be float and bash cannot operate on floats directly so you have to use `bc`:

```
if [ "$(bc -l <<< "${CPU} > ${MAX}")" -eq 1 ]
```

You should also use `$(..)` form instead of [legacy
backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) and you could assign `CPU`
only once within while loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAX=80

while true
do
    CPU="$(top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print $2 + $4}')"

    if [ "$(bc -l <<< "${CPU} > ${MAX}")" -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo "$CPU"  # This is an example
        sleep 10m
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. Just one more question for curiosity. I have to run the script now with `bash script.sh`, because `sh script.sh` does not accept `<<<`. If I would like to use `sh` instead of `bash` could I change the `<<<` for another operator? or I would have to write the script in a different way?

Comment: @Xbel: use `|` like that: `if [ "$(echo "$CPU > $MAX" | bc)" -eq 1 ]`

Answer (score 2):

`top(1)` is not the best way to solve this problem. It's a rather heavyweight measuring tool, scanning far more than you need. Besides, it's focused on instantaneous values, which isn't the right thing here.

Instead, you should use the [system load averages](https://sharadchhetri.com/4-different-commands-to-check-the-load-average-in-linux/) because they're computed continuously over long periods in the kernel. This means they carry no extra cost, thus don't impact your measurement, and they aren't affected by instantaneous changes...like calling `top(1)`!

Here's your script rewritten in terms of load averages:

```
#!/bin/bash
HIGH_LOAD=6      # 80% of an 8-core system; see link above

while true
  do
    CURR_LOAD=$(cut -f2 -d' ' < /proc/loadavg)
    if [ $CURR_LOAD -lt $HIGH_LOAD ]
      then
        run-background-command
      fi
    sleep 10m
  done
```

Note that the `sleep` call is moved outside the `if` condition: you want to delay regardless. Maybe you want to add an `else` instead so the delay is different for the low and high load cases.

Also unlike your version, we don't repeat the CPU usage check inside the loop and outside.

Comment: Thanks, as you pointed I had the problem of the measurement being instantaneous. his is a perfect solution.

Comment: @Xbel: The very act of starting `top` and having it gather dozens of statistics per process and assemble them, and only *then* pull out CPU usage will spike the CPU usage! Your process might well skip run intervals purely because your measurement process is disturbing the result.